# Throw java exception and stops

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I have a simple Java program with a `main` method and several other methods. Each method can fail with a different exception.

What I am doing now is adding a `try`-`catch` block for each method, but the problem is that if the first method fails and I catch and print the exception, the program proceeds.

I want the program to stop if any exception occurs. What is the recommended way to solve this in Java?

My current code is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Get File Path
    String filePath = null;
    try {
        filePath = getFilePath(args);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }

    // Load File content
    AtomicReference<String> content = new AtomicReference<String>();
    try {
        content.set(readYamlFile(sourceFilePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Not able to load file");
    }


    try {
        jsonStr = convert(content.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Conversion failed ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Every method has a different exception type. Should I use some generic exception and just throw it with the appropriate message, instead of using the try catch blocks?

Comment: You still need try-catch blocks even with custom exceptions. What's wrong with throwing `IOException`, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last solution, to use specific exceptions, would be more readable but could result in a lot of `Exception` subclass.

Here is a quick code update :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String filePath = getFilePath(args);
        AtomicReference<String> content = new AtomicReference<String>();
        content.set(readYamlFile(sourceFilePath));
        jsonStr = convert(content.toString());
    }  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("not found");
    } catch (ReadYamlFileException e) {
        System.out.println("Not able to load file");
    } catch (ConvertJsonExceptione) {
        System.out.println("Conversion failed ");
    }
}

private String readYamlFile(String) throws ReadYamlFileException{ ... }
private String convert(String) throws ConvertJsonException{ ... }
```

Since I try to have the `return` statements in the beginning (filter parameter) or the end of a method (correct method execution), this design is useful. 
If not, we would have multiple line that could stop a process, leading to a complicated debugging.

EDIT:

Of course, if you only need to print a text and stop there (no exception management), you can simply create your own exception in each method :

```
private String readYamlFile(String) throws IOException {
    try{
       ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Not able to load file", e);
    }
}
```

Where `e` is the original `Exception` thrown

Answer (score 3):

> I want to stop if exception occurs

You can put `return;`, `System.exit(1)`, or a `throw e;` within the `catch` blocks. Each will halt execution.

Depends on what you want, but you can use just one try block, followed by many catch blocks.

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter to System.exit have value of -1?

Comment: In this case of course - handling exception it means that program ended in a wrong way.

Comment: My mentioned methods were to only halt execution. I don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is handle the exception in the main method, which calls the other method. Create multiple catch for different Exceptions caught, print the specific message and again throw the caught exception from main.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("Executing main method ");
    try{
        Test t = new Test();            //create an object
        t.method1();                    //call method 1
        t.method2();                    //call method 2
        t.method3();                    //call method 3

    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("NullPointer Exception occured");
        throw npe;
    }catch(ArithmeticException ae){
        System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception occured");
        throw ae;
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aie){
        System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception  occured");
        throw aie;
    }catch(Exception e ){
        System.out.println("Some exception occured");
        throw e;
    }

 // will not be executed as exception is thrown above in catch block
        System.out.println("Exiting main method ");  

}



private void method1() {
        System.out.println("Executing method 1 ");

        String nullString = null;
        nullString.length();


}


private void method2(){
    System.out.println("Executing method 2 ");

    int i= 100/0;

}


private void method3(){

    System.out.println("Executing method 3 ");

    int[] myArray = new int[5];

    myArray[7]= 0;

    }


}
```

**Key Point 1** :
 If the exception occurs in the first method, the rest of the methods/code does not execute.

**Key Point 2**:
 You will still be able to handle the exception in main and print the msg.

```
    *Output from above code:*

    Executing main method 
    Executing method 1 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    NullPointer Exception occured
        at Test.method1(Test.java:38)
        at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

**Other options:**

1. Catch the exception in the called method itself, print the msg and exit the program using System.exit(1).

   ```
   private void method1() {
       System.out.println("Executing method 1 ");

   try{
       String nullString = null;
       nullString.length();
   }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Null pointer exception in method 1");
       System.exit(1);
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: You have hide a problem in this concept, there is two `try-catch` that catch `IOException` that log different message. You won't be able to do the difference in your "unique `try-catch`"

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the code execution by following ways

1 Stop the current thread and return

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
return;
```

2 By calling `System.exit(1)`

3 Just put a `return` in void returning method

4 throw exception `throw e`

Answer (score 1):

1. Refactor your code to use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
2. The number of try/catch blocks depends on a design of your app. But you should handle all exceptions in the child methods if you know how to handle its and throw up others to parents methods.

Comment: I don't see any `Closable` implementation here, so why the `try-with-resources` ?

Comment: he reads file here so underneath it uses resources. It's better not throw  such  exceptions as `IOException`  and `FileNotFoundException`   but handle it inside `try-with-resources` and throw only `CustomBuisnessException` if needed.

Comment: Well, the resource is in the method, not here. So this is/could be correct. And re-throwing the exception is better than returning `null` in some case (even if I don't follow enough my own advice ;) ).